# Why does the pH of the endpoint decrease when temperature of the titration is increased?

Tags: acid-base, equilibrium, ph

I was doing an experiment in chemistry class involving titrations. I would heat up different samples of vinegar and titrate them using NaOH. The trend that I found was how has temperature increase, the pH of the endpoint decreases. Can someone explain this to me please?

Answer (score 0):

If you were heating the solutions without covering the flasks, the evaporating water left the flask concentrating the acid, hence why you obtained a lower pH reading. Commercial vinegar is usually a 5% solution of acetic acid (CH3COOH).